# Is there an equivalent of this JS expression in Go?

Tags: javascript, string, go

Let's say we have 2 strings, str1 and str2. I want a new variable str3 to equal str1, or if str1 is empty then equal str2.

In JS I would write:

```
var str3 = str1 || str2
```

While in Go I have to do it like:

```
str3 := str1
if str1 == "" {
    str3 = str2
}
```

which is a little bit too verbose imo.
Is there an equivalent expression as the one in JS?

Comment: Note that the Go's snippet is not quite equivalent to that in JS: try your JS code with `str1` set to "false".  What I actually want to say is that when I forced to write JS, I do it much like I would do it in Go; so I'd write your snippet something like `var str3 = str1 === "" ? str2 : str1`

Comment: But there is no shorthand if in Go, right?

Comment: Luckily, no, there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent expression as the one in JS?

No, but if you find yourself doing this often, you could write a function that does what you're trying to accomplish:

```
func strs(s ...string) string {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    for _, str := range s[:len(s)-1] {
        if str != "" {
            return str
        }
    }
    return s[len(s)-1]
}
```

Usage:

```
str3 := strs(str1, str2)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Gl_06XDjW4

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent operation in Go. You have to do it with an if (or a switch, but that's even more verbose). I would write it like this:

```
var str3 string
if str1 != "" {
    str3 = str1
} else {
    str3 = str2
}
```